View update with WebSocket (Starscream)
I can't get the View update after a socket response. At the same time, I get the correct connection status by clicking the button.
Unlike this question Binding two ObservableObjects in SwiftUI
I don't have a problem with binding Observables. Everything works correctly, but the View is not updated.
How can this be solved?
import SwiftUI
import Starscream

struct WebSocketView_Test: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Status: \(viewModel.webSocketManager.isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected")")
        // I see "Status: Disconnected"
        Button("Get Status") {
            viewModel.getStatus() // return true
        }
    }
}

I use ViewModel pattern in my project, so I left it in this small example as well.
extension WebSocketView_Test {
    
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var webSocketManager: WebSocketManager_Test
        
        init() {
            self.webSocketManager = WebSocketManager_Test()
        }
        
        func getStatus() {
            print(webSocketManager.isConnected)
        }
    }
}

Here is a WebSocket class.
class WebSocketManager_Test: ObservableObject {
    let socket: WebSocket
    @Published var isConnected = false
    
    init() {
        socket = WebSocket(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://echo.websocket.org")!))
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }
}

extension WebSocketManager_Test: WebSocketDelegate {
    func didReceive(event: Starscream.WebSocketEvent, client: Starscream.WebSocketClient) {
        switch event {
        case .connected(let headers):
            print("websocket is connected: \(headers as AnyObject)")
            isConnected = true
        default:
            print("something")
        }
    }
}

If I add a timer and refresh View on it, everything works. But this is obviously an incorrect solution.
